# VBA Excel sine cosine functions

Tags: excel, vba, trigonometry

I am trying to write a short trig function wanting to use sine and cosine functions in VB and I am very new to this as it's my first time coding in VB.

See what I'm trying to accomplish below:

```
Function XXX(HR, HR_RL, abc)

Const PI As Double = "3.141593"

AC = Sqr(HR ^ 2 + HR_RL ^ 2 - 2 * HR * HR_RL * Cos(abc * PI / 180))
```

VB is complaining about two things Cos and Sqr.

It seems they are both built-in VBA functions, but somehow I can't get them evaluated and as a result, AC variable = empty.

In fact, it doesn't seem that it even goes past "Cos(abc * PI / 180)". If I substitute "Cos(abc * PI / 180)" with a numeric value (just to see where else is another problem), surely enough, now VB complains about "Sqr".

Comment: What kind of "complaints"?  What are your data inputs to the function?  Using some random numbers, it seems to run OK here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, checking "System" didn't work.  There is no complaint. The function just returns 0. In the debug mode, I can hoover over or high-light individual variables or terms. It shows AC=empty. High-lighting "abc*PI/180" shows the right calc, but high-lighting "Cos(abc*PI/180)" doesn't show anything.

Comment: Repeating:  *What are your data inputs to the function?*  Edit your question to show that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I don't fully understand you question, but HR, HR_RL, and abc are just numbers.  If you are referring to the data type, I think they are variants since I didn't separately declare their types.

Comment: And what are those numbers? Did they come from a cell or are you inputting them from another VBA macro?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, from cells.

Comment: **And what are the actual numbers??**

Comment: HR = 4.9, HR_RL = 2.4, abc = 171.0963

Comment: I get a result of `7.280562`.  You only posted a portion of your code.  Perhaps your error is in the unposted portion.

Comment: What I posted above is literally all I have except for End Function at the end.  Maybe I didn't set things up right at all.  Like I said, I am very new.  All I did was: Alt+F11, Insert Module, typed the above in the Editor, and from a cell, I typed "=XXX(A1, A2, A3)".  I must be something global, then.

Comment: What you posted is lacking both an `End Function` line and also `XXX = AC` line.  Without the first, you should be seeing a compile error; without the second, you will be getting a `0` result.

Comment: Thank you.  It worked.  How can I make your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your VBA Editor menu and select `Tools -> References...`, then check the `System` library. It will give you access to all the math functions.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I've never checked that reference, in either Excel 2007 or 2016, and I've never had an issue with the VBA Trig functions.

Comment: @PeterT, checking "System" didn't work. There is no complaint. The function just returns 0. In the debug mode, I can hoover over or high-light individual variables or terms. It shows AC=empty. High-lighting "abcPI/180" shows the right calc, but high-lighting "Cos(abcPI/180)" doesn't show anything.

Comment: There is no "return" of the result from your function. Add `XXX = AC` at the end of the function and see if it works.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - interestingly, when I first tested this in my default VBA set up, the trig functions didn't work. So a quick google search and checking the `System` reference did the trick. Since I don't generally need `System`, I didn't save this configuration. Today, when I tested a bit of code based on your comment, I can get sin/cos/sqr to work just fine without checking `System`. Very strange indeed.